# jQuery handing both focus and click on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, mouse

I'm trying to determine workflow to fine-tune a data entry web application.  Picture several address forms on a single web page:

```
  1. Name___________
     Street_________
     Phone__________

  2. Name___________
     Street_________
     Phone__________

  [...many more...]
```

Now I'd like to know if the user is using the tab key to get to the second "Name" field (or anywhere within that record), or if they're using the mouse to click on it.  (Or shift-tab to move in reverse.)

I've set a handler on both focus and click for the input fields:

```
$('input').click(function() { TabulateClick(this) });
$('input').focus(function() { TabulateFocus(this) });
```

And in the handler, I determine which address the user is working on and whether we've "switched" Address records.  (If the focus was in "Phone" for the first address, and you click on the "Name" field in the *same address*, that's not actually switching records, so I don't tabulate that.)

```
    function TabulateClick(field)
    {
         var currentAddressRecord = FindAddress(field);
         if ( lastAddressRecord != currentAddressRecord )
             switchedAddressesWithClick++;
         lastAddressRecord = currentAddress;
    }
    function TabulateFocus(field)
    {
         var currentAddress = FindAddress(field);
         if ( lastAddressRecord != currentAddressRecord )
             switchedAddressesWithTab++;
         lastAddressRecord = currentAddress;
    }
```

My problem is that when I mouse-click into the field the `focus` event fires first tabulating a false `switchedAddressesWithTab` and changing the currentAddress (that's **bad**).  When the `click` handler runs, the `lastAddressRecord` is spoiled.

Is there a way inside of the `focus` handler to know that there is a pending `click` event on the same object?  Or in the `click` handler to know that it was previously just handled by `focus`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's something that I think works based on the fact that the mousedown happens before the focus. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvtMC/1/).

```
var lastClick = null;
$('input').mousedown(function(e) {
  lastClick = e.target;
}).focus(function(e){
    if (e.target == lastClick) {
      console.log('click');
    } else {
      console.log('tab');    
    }
    lastClick = null;

});
```

To fix the bug discovered by Josiah, I changed my code to the below. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvtMC/4/).

```
var lastFocusedElement = null;
var isClick = false;
$('input').mousedown(function(e) {     
     isClick= true;
}).focus(function(e){

    // To prevent focus firing when element already had focus
    if (lastFocusedElement != e.target) {
        if (isClick) {
          console.log('click ----');
        } else {
          console.log('tab -----');    
        }
        lastFocusedElement = e.target;
        isClick = false;
    }
});

$(document.body).focus(function(){
  lastFocusedElement = document.body;
});
```

The one problem is that you don't get 'click' or tab when you switch away from the window and switch back. You get a focus event on the input that had focus, but you can't determine if it's a tab or a click, because it's neither.

I think this is the closest you'll get, I would try this on your page and see if the behavior is good enough.

Comment: @Juan - since we are into QA today, when you tab through all the fields to the body, then click into one the console logs click,tab

Comment: @Josiah: Good catch, I don't understand why it's happening though... I guess we provided the OP with two ways that work most of time, still investing another 2 minutes on this though

Comment: @Juan - yah thanks for talking me into spending entirely more time then i ever anticipated on this question ;) what can we do, dang developers.

Comment: @Josiah, @Juan -- Don't feel bad, I spent all morning on it.  :)

Comment: Not sure why 'focus' fires twice after tabbing out of the last field (into the location bar) then clicking it again, that's what causes my solution to fail

Comment: This is by far the closest solution i found online. But there is one use case. I have a toggler on click. So ii want to be able to click multiple times on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in jQuery. Here is another way to bind both events on the same element.

```
var hasClicked = false;
$('.myinputfield').on('mousedown : click',function(e){
     if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        // execute code
        hasClicked = true;
     }
     if(e.type == 'focus' && !hasClicked) {
        //execute code
        console.log(e.type)
     }
     hasClicked = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the focus and then check the event to see if `e.which == 9 // tab`.

My original idea did not work (thanks @Juan). Using the combination of events should get you where you want to be. 
If the user clicks into the text box the last key press will not be a tab. All inputs are watching and storing the last key code to pass to the focus event. 
[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvtMC/2/)

```
var lastKeyCode = 0;
$('input').focus(function(e) {
    if(lastKeyCode == 9)
         // tabbed into field
    else
         // clicked into field
}).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 9) // added timeout to clear lastkeypress
        setTimeout(function(){lastKeyPress = 0}, 50);
    lastKeyPress = e.which; // store last key code
});
```

Comment: mmm, very interesting, is this tested?

Comment: @Josiah: I don't think this works--In FF I get undefined even if I tab into the field.

Comment: Doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/3py9V/. If you suggest something that is untested, you should mention that your answer is an untested suggestion

Comment: You'd be better off keeping the previous answer, and adding an update, otherwise the comments don't make sense. This still doesn't work though... if you click on the second input, then click tab, then click back into either input, it'll think it's a tab. Works most of the time though

Comment: @Juan - I left the first line which summed up my original idea. The one issue you pointed out could be fixed with a timeout.

Comment: @Josiah - Timeouts or delays would be really bad.  This is a data-entry application, and users tend to be very sensitive to timing.  Introducing a hesitation is a really bad thing.

Comment: Posted something else that I think works all the time, can somebody try to break it?

Comment: The code above... once you've tabbed every click is reported as a 'tab'.  Getting closer, maybe?

Comment: @clintp - hmm which browser? im not seeing that behavior in chrome. Also the timeout is only a 50ms when the tab key is pressed.

Comment: 50ms here, 50ms there... Adding timeouts, delayed action, etc.. just smells bad, like a cop-out of some kind.  If that's the way it has to be, so be it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: @clintp - i would agree to an extent. It does sort of feel like a cop-out, but then if you have done much javascript timeouts are as fundamental as functions and variables in single threaded development.

Comment: global variable is lastKeyCode at top of code. keydown handler uses lastKeyPress.