# Prevent the focus from the selected element

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an HTML calculator in my web page. What I'm trying to do is select an `input` field, then enter values by clicking on numbered `div` elements but when I click on the `input` and after on the `div`, the focus comes to the `div`. How can I prevent this using jQuery.

[image: HTML calculator]

In the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJ4ZT/1/) you'll see that when I click on the input element and try to enter the values, the focus will leave! How can I fix this and record the relevant value in the input field?

Comment: if you prevent this the click won't be catched on the div which you need, rather in the div click handle return the focus to your input.

Comment: You'd better make a jsFiddle simple example with some code, instead of screenshot.

Comment: focus should come or should not come to input field?

Comment: Handle the focus. Maybe this could help : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889355/jquery-handing-both-focus-and-click-on-an-element

Answer (score 0):

define a variable on document ready

`var focusedInput;`

if focus changes to any input store that input in focusedInput

`focusedInput = $(this);`

on div click write your code

`$('div.num-button').click( function(){`

`//some code here`

`$(focusedInput).focus(); //handle null exception`

`});`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, however, if anyone else comes looking this answer might be helpful.

As @anil said, create a variable in which you may store your focused input. Then when you focus on your input, store the element in the variable. Now when you click on your "keypad" get the value and add it to the focused variable input value.

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ootred/k1ajfvg9/1/) that I branched from you original fiddle.

This is the code:

```
var focused;
// Stored the input
$('input').focus(function() {
    focused = $(this);
});

// Listen for clicks on the number button
$('.num-button').click(function(){
    // Get the value of the number button that was clicked as string
    var intVal = $(this).find('span').text().toString();
    // Make sure that we have a focused input
    if(typeof focused != 'null' || typeof focused != 'undefined') {
        // Only add numbers to the input field
        if(intVal != "DONE" && intVal != "Del") {
            // Get the values as strings
            var curVal = focused.val().toString(),
                newVal = curVal + intVal;
            focused.val(newVal);
        } else if (intVal == "Del") {
            // Clear the value if the Del "key" was clicked.
            focused.val('');
        }
    }
});
```