# Focus on click?

Tags: jquery, click, focus

Is there any easy way to trigger jQuery .focus on a link after clicking on it? Maybe there's a jQuery event mixing these?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="focus">Focus</a>
<a href="#" class="click">Click</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Focus Code
    $('.focus').focus(function(){
        alert('focus!');
    });

    // My noobish try to focus on click, will probably break the universe
    /* $('.focus').click(function(){
        $(this).focus();
    }); */

    // This should work, but I want this link to really FOCUS
    /* $('.focus').click(function(){
        alert('focus!');
    }); */

    // Click Code
    $('.click').click(function(){
        alert('click!');
    })

})
```

I want to alert "focus!" after clicking on "Focus" link, not only pressing the TAB.

There was similar question, but it's more complex and over 2 years old: [jQuery handing both focus and click on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889355/jquery-handing-both-focus-and-click-on-an-element)

Here's jsfiddle to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVTKc/

Comment: Could you explain more clearly the part you want after your code ?

Comment: Originally I have a link and want this link to do something if user clicks it OR if user jumps trough links pressing TAB. Looks like .click works only in the first case and .focus only in the second one. In addition I want the link to do something else when it loses focus (or when user clicks elsewhere).

Comment: Of course I won't use any alerts, in fact I'm trying to create an input that resizes on click / focus and then comes back to original size after losing focus / clicking outside of it (kind of Apple.com search form).

Comment: A click will focus the element. You don't need to explicitly handle both cases.

Comment: @MattBall, I thought so, but looks like nothing happens after clicking on "focus" link... Then press the TAB and bang, it works...

Comment: @Wordpressor honestly I still don't understand what you want(the focus/Focus is kinda confusing) but try using this to debug and let me know if it helps `$('.focus').hover(function(){
        alert(this.hasFocus);
    });` basically just helping debug :)

Comment: @woofmeow, here's highly simplified example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/YdCPe/1/

Comment: try this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YdCPe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is have focus fired on click,TAB and focus events.

To see the `console.log()` that i am using below open the console in your browser.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="focus-test">Focus Test</a>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.focus-test').focus(function(){
        //not using alert because it causes a loop because you re-focus after you dismiss the alert.
        console.log('focus and click');
    });
    $('.focus-test').click(function(){
        this.focus();
    });
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVTKc/4/

---

Just to add comment you should never fire events yourself instead call a function to handle both events, see code below.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="focus-test">Focus Test</a>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.focus-test').focus(function(){
        userInteraction();
    });
    $('.focus-test').click(function(){
        userInteraction();
    });
    function userInteraction(){
        //not using alert because it causes a loop because you re-focus after you dismiss the alert.
        console.log('focus and click and tab');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JVTKc/5/