# Open a dropdown menu when it receives focus via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I have a navbar with a couple dropdown menus. Long story short, it's hard-coded into our site, and we need to find a way to trigger these dropdowns without the mouse. I have tried other methods, but as of now I want to use this one:

As a blind user tabs through the menu, I would like the dropdowns to open when they receive focus. I believe I just need the correct syntax to actually trigger this but I cannot find it. I am using this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testF").on("focus",function() {
        $(this).dropdown("open");
    });
});
```

My problem seems to lie within the .navbar-toggle("open"); (wrong syntax)
I am simply trying to figure out how this dropdown will open as it comes into focus? Any help will be much appreciated, here is some of the dropdown HTML incase it helps:

```
<li class="dropdown">                                    
    <a id="testF" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Courses<span class="caret" /></a>                                       
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
             <a href="/home/BbDeepLink" target="_blank">All Courses (click here)</a>
        </li>
```

CSS:

```
/* Menu */
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
        color:#222;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color:#222;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#5396b1;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#5396b1;
    }
    .dropdown-menu{
        padding:0px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 781px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Fixes: The main menu hover/focus dropdown issue */
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open ul  {
        display:none;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open:hover ul {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also post the CSS associated with your drop down

Comment: just use `.navbar-toggle()` (no parameters).

Comment: still no luck, I have edited the question to include the CSS

Comment: NOTE: the dropdown does open on mouse hover, just doesn't react when tabbed to on keyboard

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testF").on("focus",function() {
        $("#testF").click();
   });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Provide information to support your code.

Comment: I really liked this `click` approach!

Comment: I get a jQuery "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this : [jQuery handing both focus and click on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889355/jquery-handing-both-focus-and-click-on-an-element).

The idea is to detect if it was a focus after a tab or a mouse click.

```
var lastClick = null;
    $('#testF').mousedown(function (e) {
        lastClick = e.target;
    }).focus(function (e) {
        if (e.target != lastClick) {
            $(this).dropdown("toggle");
        }
        lastClick = null;

    });
```

Hope this is an acceptable answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
$("#testF").select2();
$("#testF").next(".select2").find(".select2-selection").focus(function() {
    $("#testF").select2("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon trial and error I reached my desired results (almost, need to blur away now so it doesn't stay open, tips welcome!) with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testF").on("focus",function() {
            $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").toggle()

        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

this my solution:

```js
$("#dropdownMenuButton").on("focus", elements => {
    var element = elements.currentTarget;
    $(element).dropdown("toggle");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <h1>Teste de Menu</h1>
                    <div class="dropdown dropright">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Menu
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129942/open-a-dropdown-menu-when-it-receives-focus-via-jquery#    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </main>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```